# style.display="none"; doesn't work with javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom, onclick, modal-dialog

a beginner here, i'm trying to make a modal that will be shown once the **share** button is clicked and i don't seem to find why the **onclick** function isn't executed, the idea is once the **share** button is clicked the **display:none;** will be changed to **display:block**, so either there is a problem with **style.display="block"** or, which is more probable, i suck .
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you previously.

HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar-container">
  <div class="nav nav-1" >
    <button class="btn btn-1" id="sharebtn">Share </button>
  </div>

  <div class="nav nav-2">
    <button class="btn btn-2"  id="howbtn">how does it work ?</button>      
</div>
<div class="nav nav-3" >
    <button class="btn btn-3"  id="abouttns">About</button>
</div>
</div>


  <!---Creating the modals-->
<div id="modal-share">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close-share">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
        <input type="text" class="link-input" placeholder="www.youtube.com/jdlkfsjakfdsa">
        <button id="share-btn" onclick="fuck">share</button>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <input type="text" max="50" placeholder="cats are not that smart">
    </div>
    
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
    #modal-share{
        display: none; /*hidden by default*/
        position: fixed; /*staying in the center even when scrolling*/
        z-index: 1; /*stays on top of grids, 3D translation*/
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: white; /*color of the modal*/
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  /*color of the background*/
        border:1px solid black;

    }
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var modal=document.getElementById("modal-share");
    var share_btn=document.getElementsById("sharebtn");
    var close_share=document.getElementsByClassName("close-share");


   

    share_btn.onclick=function(){
        modal.style.display="block";
    }
    close_share.onclick=function(){
        modal.style.display="none";
    }

    window.onclick=function(event){
        if(event.target==modal){
            modal.style.display="none";
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an error in your script which is causing everything else to fail, namely

```
var share_btn=document.getElementsById("sharebtn");
```

There is no function document.getElement**s**ById, only document.getElementById. I have your code working with the fix on the following link -

https://jsfiddle.net/2pfzc4gL/

Answer (score 1):

Two things, first there's a typo in your code `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`. And the second is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like collection of elements so you need to retrieve the first one from the array. Here's the updated javascript.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("modal-share");
const share_btn = document.getElementById("sharebtn"); // typo here in original
const close_share = document.getElementsByClassName("close-share")[0]; // select first element in HTML collection

share_btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
    
close_share.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
 
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `typo` in your script which is causing the issue.

```
var share_btn=document.getElementsById("sharebtn");
```

it should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`.

it would be better if we use `querySelector` for querying DOM element and for events `addEventListener` instead of overriding the click function

```
var share_btn = document.querySelector("#sharebtn");
var close_share = document.querySelector(".close-share");
var modal = document.querySelector("#modal-share");

share_btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});
close_share.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
});

window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```